# Q value for the absorbing state

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

```
\begin{equation}
​Q_{t+1}(s_t,a_t) = Q_{t}(s_t,a_t) +\alpha
(R_{t+1} + \gamma * \max(Q_t(s_{t+1}, a)) - Q_t(s_t, a_t))
\end{equation}
```

In above equation,there is a term `max(Q_t(s_{t+1},a))`
Now say after you take an action in state `s_t` resulting in s`_{t+1}`. There are no available moves in s_{t+1}. The game has ended in draw, What is this `max(Q_t(s_{t+1},a))` then?

Answer (score 2):

The value of terminal (aka absorbing) states are 0 by definition in V and Q functions, as it can be read in [Section 3.7](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node34.html) of Rich Sutton's book:

[image]

Comment: Can you please mention the definition.

Comment: Thanks, if possible please include the explicit definition in the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia if your question was correctly answered, could you please mark the answer as accepted? Thanks.